# should I be calling lckpwdf() prior to getspent()?

Tags: c, linux, etcpasswd

Is `lckpwdf()` and `ulckpwdf()` intended to be used only for apps directly accessing the shadow password file?

More precisely, my question is:  If I call the usual API such as `getspnam()` or `getspent()`, should I be calling `lckpwdf()` first, or is that automatically done by `getspnam()`, etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `lckpwdf()` unless you are planing on making changes to the shadow file. `lckpwdf()` created an exclusive lock on the file, which causes any process trying to access the file wait until the lock is released. For reading the shadow file, this is highly unnecessary.

If you are modifying the file, call `lckpwdf()` once before your modifications, process with your modifications, and then call `ulckpwdf()`. Also, if you run into an exception, make sure to call `ulckpwdf()`.

Comment: Then you need to call lckpwdf()  before your modifications and then ulckpwdf() after. Post modified.

Comment: setspent() and putspent() doesn't automatically lock the file.